# How to get rid of Error in my Git imported JS project

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I imported a project from Git into my Eclipse.
The project is in Javascript language.

I see an error message in the .js files, see screenshot attached.
Error displayed at line "`exports.handler = async (event) => {`", Error says "Unexpected token =>"

I'm completely new to Git, any help here??? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: it doesn't have anything to do with git. I think that eclipse doesn't parse arrow function. I suggest you to use another IDE like VS Code or Webstorm for you js code

Comment: How old is this release of Eclipse?

Comment: @DevangSaklani Just use [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) to get same (same, not equal) JavaScript/TypeScript, etc. language support in Eclipse.

Comment: @R4ncid This is not true, as you can confirm yourself with the given example.